# Effective way to query BMC Helix Remedy database other than Smart Reporting

Tags: remedy

Currently we are connecting the AR System through the Oracle database for this purpose. I need to know: is there any alternative way to access or query the Remedy database effectively? Is there any built-in API which we can utilise which will increase the efficiency of the work?

Answer (score 0):

What could be used is the REST api, in which you can query directly the forms.
Please check following url:
[REST API Doc](https://docs.bmc.com/docs/itsm2102/overview-of-the-rest-api-974495995.html)

It will result with JSON object containing all data.
In order to obtain access to all forms you need to create a "service" user with fixed license and permissions to the forms which you would like to read using the API call.

Comment: We have seen this. But our purpose is to kind of execute various queries with SQL joins and all kind of fetching data for reporting can you provide such a use case if possible. We are completely newb on this one. Thanks alot for helping us.

Comment: If you have defined a set of queries which would be executed on a regular basis you can also use Atrium Spoon which is also accessible for SaaS Helix, this tool allows to use SQL as an input which is called "Table Input" - Table input step allows you to read information from a database, using a connection and SQL. Basic SQL statements are generated automatically.
You can e.g. output to a text file.

please check more on https://docs.bmc.com/docs/ac91/adding-intermediate-steps-to-a-atrium-integrator-transformation-609847235.html

Answer (score 0):

You can query the Oracle back-end directly, with a few caveats. It should only be for reading data, not writing or modifying data. Otherwise, you could break data integrity as well as bypass workflow that should be fired. Also, this direct access does not enforce any permissions, nor does it translate any of the data. For example, selection fields come back as a number instead of their string value, dates are in epoch format, etc.

There is a Remedy ODBC driver, which isn't being updated, nor does it support joins. However, you can open multiple connections with it and join them manually. Plus, it does handle permissions and translations for you.
https://docs.bmc.com/docs/ars1911/odbc-database-access-introduction-896318914.html

If you know in advance what joins you will be doing, you should setup join forms within Remedy. That way the joins are done efficiently in the database. Otherwise, you are stuck with either of the above solutions or using one of the APIs which don't support ad-hoc joins.